# What is the best way to breakdown huge CSV's based on a condition?

Tags: python, bigdata

I have 10 CSV files, each of them are around 40-60 GB's. 
I wanted to know the most efficient way without using Spark/Hadoop to do something like slicing a CSV based on a condition and store them as CSV's.

For example, consider a Table Machine_Details
+--------------+--------+--------+

| Machine_Name | Value1 | Value2 |

+--------------+--------+--------+

|         1203 | 0.11   | 0.22   |

|         1203 | 0.21   | 0.23   |

|         1205 | 0.21   | 0.45   |

+--------------+--------+--------+

What I want is that all the rows related to 1203 Machine Name should be put into one CSV and similarly all rows with Machine Name 1205 should be put into another CSV

Comment: have you already tried an iterative approach?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Yes, I am doing that currently, Reading in the Pandas DAtaframe as chunks and parsing them. But, was hoping to find some other efficient method

Comment: @RoshanJoeVincent, applying pandas is a good start. I would also distribute the processing on 10 processes (1 process per file)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about most efficient, but if I needed to do something like this, I might utilize Pandas. 
1. I'd convert each csv to a dataframe.
2. with in each dataframe, I'd create a list of unique values for your column.
3. then use a boolean variable to filter each CSV with respect to your list of unique values.
4. after filtering each dataframe you can then covert each to it's own CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into AWK (see e.g. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/awk-command-unixlinux-examples/ ), which is a standard utility in many Linux distributions. From the site I linked to:

> Awk is a utility that enables a programmer to write tiny but effective
>   programs in the form of statements that define text patterns that are
>   to be searched for in each line of a document and the action that is
>   to be taken when a match is found within a line. Awk is mostly used
>   for pattern scanning and processing. It searches one or more files to
>   see if they contain lines that matches with the specified patterns and
>   then performs the associated actions.